# Customise Unique Id generate in PHP , MySql

Tags: php, mysql, unique-id

I want little help in creating automated but custom id for each item i store in mysql database. Like if i enter 1 item of pepe jeans color "black" and waist 30. the unique id for this product will be PEPE+BLACK+30+A001, A001 is an unique number which will increase like A001, A002, A003....A999 after reaching A999 this number will become B001 and then B002,B003....so on. Plz show me the logic to do this.

Example of 1 item id will be: PEPEBLACK30A009

#thanks :)

Comment: If you already have A001-A999 how is the next number A201?

Comment: thats the main problem, how i can do this through coding .

Comment: The point I was making was that you have already used A201 in your initial set of data (A001 through A999)

Comment: Opps, i am so sorry thats a typing mistake, it will become B001 and so on

Comment: if the entities in the final code were delimited, with a dash for example, it would be easier to target the final entity and thus increment it's numeric index.

Comment: Hello Sir @Fluffeh plz help.

Comment: Didn't get you sir @RamRaider

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want this?

Comment: @Strawberry client want it like this only -_-

Comment: Well, I think you (and possibly your client) are confusing data storage with data retrieval and display.

Comment: nah not me :| @Strawberry

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like that:

```
$lastId = 'A999';
$letter = $lastId[0];
echo $letter;
$number = $lastId[1].$lastId[2].$lastId[3];
echo $number;

if ($number < 999) {
    $newId = $letter.sprintf("%03d", $number+1);
} else {
    $ascii = ord($letter);
    $newLetter = chr($ascii+1);
    $newId = $newLetter.'001';
}

echo $newId;
```

Just keep in mind that after the character Z this will print other symbols so it might need some tweeking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary ID column where it auto increments (0 - 28971), then you can take this ID number and convert it into your format.

Example of a few IDs converted:

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i += 99) {
    $num     = $i;
    $letters = range('A', 'Z');
    $letter  = (int) $num / 999;
    $num     = $num % 999 + 1;
    $num     = str_pad($num, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo $i . ' => ' . $letters[$letter] . $num . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0 => A001
99 => A100
198 => A199
297 => A298
396 => A397
495 => A496
594 => A595
693 => A694
792 => A793
891 => A892
990 => A991
1089 => B091
1188 => B190
1287 => B289
1386 => B388
1485 => B487
1584 => B586
1683 => B685
1782 => B784
1881 => B883
1980 => B982
2079 => C082
2178 => C181
2277 => C280
2376 => C379
2475 => C478
2574 => C577
2673 => C676
2772 => C775
2871 => C874
2970 => C973
```

[Rest](https://eval.in/private/d90378158dfb11)

An issue is of course, the limit of 28971 for the primary key, because there's only 26 letters (26 * 999), but of course you can have 4/more numbers, or add more letters in the future.